# Python query objects are not serializable

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, serialization, jinja2

When I tried to encode the query objects I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Program File\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
      File "C:\Program File\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 178, in default
        raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    TypeError: ActivitySummaries(key=Key('ActivitySummaries', 634), activated_users=0, broker_approved=0, broker_registered=0, broker_searched=1, closed_deals=0, company_registered=0, company_searched=4, deal_appoved=0, investor_approved=0, investor_registered=0, investor_searched=3, registered_users=0, timestamp=datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 8, 20, 41, 47, 574000), watchlisting=0) is not JSON serializable
```

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        data: someData,
        url: someUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error : function(request, status, thrownError){
            alert("Error");
            return;
                }
    });
```

Handler:

```
 search_pattern = roledb.ActivitySummaries.searchPatterns(start_date, end_date)

            self.response.write(json.dumps(search_pattern))
```

roledb.py

```
class ActivitySummaries(ndb.Model):    
    def searchPatterns(cls, start_date, end_date):
            activities = cls.query()
            results = []
            for activity in activities:
                if ( activity.timestamp >= start_date and activity.timestamp <= end_date ):
                    results.append(activity)

            return results
```

I'm new to Google App Engine and I have no idea why it cannot be serializable using JSON.

Any inputs will be heartily appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can serialize only "simple" data types in Python, like dictionaries, arrays etc.  So you should serialize not the query object, but the result of this query—I guess it'll be an array.

Another solution is to subclass [JSONEncoder](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) to handle arbitrary values, like the snippet I did for DateTime:

```
import datetime
from json import JSONEncoder

class DateEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And to use it specify `cls=DateEncoder`:

```
json.dumps(data, cls=DateEncoder)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize pretty much anything you want to JSON but beyond simple structures you will need to do it all yourself.  And write your own unpickers.

However in your case I doubt it makes any sense to serialize a Query object. What will you do with it at the other end ?  Javascript can't do anything with it, and if you just want to pass query parameters around then just pass those around rather than a Query object.

Maybe you actually want to serialize the result set from the query and pass that back to the client.  In that case do a fetch, or use a cursor to retrieve chunks of results.

The ndb.Model base class has a to_dict() method, which is what you would normally call and you would then serialize the dictionary.

```
result = json.dumps([dumps(i.to_dict()) for i in query.fetch(100))
```

or even better use the map method of query  (there is even a map_async)

```
def dump(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj.to_dict())

result = query.map(dump)
```

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#map

You will need to combine this with the other answer, to provide a custom encoder for dates and any other non simple data type.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it using to_dict() method?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following solution worked for serializing `ndb.Model` objects which contain `ndb.DateTimeProperty` as children.

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

__author__ = 'achuinard'

class GaeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return int(obj.strftime('%s'))
        elif isinstance(obj, ndb.Model):
            return obj.to_dict()
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def serialize(object_to_serialize):
    return json.dumps(object_to_serialize, cls=GaeEncoder)
```