# How to serialize the result of a query in python?

Tags: json, google-app-engine, serialization, python-2.7

I'm having trouble to serialize the result array from a query where one of its projection is of datetime property.

My model class looks as follows:

```
class ActivitySummaries(ndb.Model):
    registered_users = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    activated_users = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    company_registered = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    broker_registered = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    investor_registered = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    deal_approved = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    broker_approved = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    investor_approved = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    company_searched = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    broker_searched = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    investor_searched = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    watchlisting = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    closed_deals = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

Query:

activities = cls.query()
```

**I want to send the the result array of the query in serialized form from Python using JSON and de-serialize in JavaScript using JSON.**

I'm getting the following error:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: ActivitySummaries(key=Key('ActivitySummaries', 923), activated_users=0, broker_approved=0, broker_registered=0, broker_searched=1, closed_deals=0, company_registered=0, company_searched=1, deal_approved=0, investor_approved=0, investor_registered=0, investor_searched=0, registered_users=0, timestamp=datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 21, 22, 14, 28, 48000), watchlisting=0) is not JSON serializable
```

So I tried to use a subclass to handle the arbitrary value which is as follows:

```
import datetime
from json import JSONEncoder

class DateEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And call it using `json.dumps(data, cls=DateEncoder)`

But I still get the same error.

I have read somewhere that NDB Class has to_dict() built in method which we would normally call and then serialize the dictionary. Can any one help me out to serialize for this particular instance using to_dict(). I can provide you more details of the code if necessary.

**P.S : My project is not using "Django" or "simplejson".**

Comment: Have you searched SO before posting the question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311363/appengine-making-ndb-models-json-serializable

Comment: I did just answer your question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351286/python-query-objects-are-not-serializable

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON serialization of Google App Engine models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531501/json-serialization-of-google-app-engine-models)

Answer (score 1):

Many options elsewhere. One of them, from http://blog.codevariety.com/2012/01/06/python-serializing-dates-datetime-datetime-into-json/:

```
def date_handler(obj):
    return obj.isoformat() if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat') else obj

print json.dumps(data, default=date_handler)
```

Note than in your example, you should have used 'default=' instead of 'cls='.

Comment: I get a "ValueError: Circular reference detected" when using this. Any idea why?